# Man in blue shirt

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is it possible to omit the "shirt" and still have the same meaning? What if it wasn't "shirt" and it was some other type of clothing, would it still be possible?

**Edit:** I meant as if there is no other person wearing a blue shirt.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking here, but *man in blue* would be a man dressed entirely in blue, so it is different to *man in [a] blue shirt* where only the shirt is blue. If it is his trousers that are blue instead of his shirt then yes, of course *man in blue trousers* is possible.

Comment: @RoaringFish So I would not be able to use it if the man isn't entirely in blue?

Comment: Although out of context (out of the blue :)) 'the man in blue' would require him to be predominantly wearing blue, in context, given a bunch of men with white shirts and different coloured trousers, "the man in blue" would pick out the one with the blue trousers (and similarly if all the men had white trousers and different coloured shirts.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yeah, I know. Imagine a situation like this: Some people in white shirts. Someone else in a red shirt. Someone else in a blue shirt. Could I use it here? This was my real question, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Sadra I'm not sure your comment has clarified things... Are you asking about the phrase "two people in white, one in red, one in blue" or that situation in the world? If you're asking about the situation, then what's the language you want to use to describe it?  If you're asking about the phrase, it would be interpreted (with no other context as something like "predominantly" in {white, red, blue}.

Comment: @AlanMunn I edited my question. I'm asking if it's possible to omit the clothing part if nobody else is wearing that color. I'm definitely bad in explaining. :/

Comment: You can omit it, but then without other context to tell you that it's shirt colour that sets people apart, readers won't necessarily assume that the person is wearing a blue shirt, but just that the predominant colour of their clothing is blue, nothing more.

Comment: @AlanMunn Okay, that has solved it. You or someone else can add that as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit 'shirt', but then without other context to tell you that it's shirt colour that sets people apart, readers won't necessarily assume that the person is wearing a blue shirt, but just that the predominant colour of their clothing is blue, nothing more.

Furthermore, although out of context (out of the blue :)) "the man in blue" would require him to be predominantly wearing blue, in context, given a bunch of men with white shirts and different coloured trousers, "the man in blue" would pick out the one with the blue trousers (and similarly if all the men had white trousers and different coloured shirts.)